# running SSH script command from jenkins using SSH

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh, putty

To deploy application on linux `ubuntu` server I have bunch of SSH commands that i currently run using PuTTY. The server has local account `serviceaccount1`. In PuTTY i connect to server using serviceaccount1 and executes the following commands one by one

```
cd /home/serviceaccount1/cr-ml
script /dev/null
screen -S data_and_status
cd cr-ml/notebooks
source activate crml
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
jupyter kernelgateway --api='kernel_gateway.notebook_http' --seed_uri='data_and_status_api.ipynb' --port 8894 --ip 0.0.0.0
...
...
and so on
```

Now i want automate this using Jenkins. I installed [SSH](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin) plugin, configured credential using SSH Username `serviceaccount1` with private key

Then created a new jenkins project and added a build step `Execute shell scripts on remote host using ssh` and then add all the above commands.
When i build the jenkins project, it get stuck at executing 2nd command `script /dev/null`
i see the following console output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems the culprit is the `screen -S data_and_status` command. Once you start a `screen`, I don't think you would be able to execute the subsequent commands over the SSH connection.

Alternatively, you can try using a tool like Ansible to run a bunch of commands against a remote server.

Comment: but `screen -S data_and_status` command runs after `script /dev/null`..its getting stuck at script command

Comment: Does `script` command print any output? I have a feeling that it has completed and `screen` is stuck. The plugin could be printing the command name after it completes. Can you try running it without the `screen` command?